QueryDsl- Dynamically add operator in search query
Below is the Mongo DB Document class
@Document
Public class MetadataMaster
{

    private String type;

    private MetadataChild metadata

    //getters and setters

}


Public class MetadataChild
{
    private Long  req_Id;
    private Localdate  create_Date
    private Integer  amount

//getters and setters

}

Along  with search criteria , I also get operator (eq, ne etc.) from the user. Instead of manually writing query statement for each field, I want to capture the search params in a  map like below.
  Public class SearchParam 
    {
        private String value;
        private String operator
    
    //getters and setters

}

 Map <String,SearchParam >

 1. type ,  SearchParam ("INV", "eq")
 2. req_Id ,  SearchParam ("red100", "eq")
 3. amount,  SearchParam ("2000", "ge")
 4. create_Date, SearchParam ("2022-04-23", "ge")

I tried the below logic. and it works fine . But I cant add operator in the below logic in a dynamic way based on the user input
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
PathBuilder<ProductInfo> path = new PathBuilder<>(MetadataMaster.class, "metadataMaster");

    if(searchMap!= null && !searchMap.isEmpty()) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, SearchParam> entry : searchMap.entrySet()) {
             SearchParam p=entry.getValue())
            builder.and(path.getString("metadata."entry.getKey()).eq(p.getValue()));    
        }
    }

Much appreciate your  help on dynamically adding operator in the above code block
